# People that cannot hear words when music is played

Tags: word-request

I would like to know whether there is a word to describe a condition whereby a person cannot hear some or all words pertaining to songs when played and needs to be able to observe the text in order to follow the words along with the song being played.

This can happen to everyone to some extent, especially language learners, but I wanted to know whether there is a word for this condition in fully proficient people.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you demonstrate that this is a real condition. For example, is there a word for it in any other language?

Comment: Maybe the Wernicke's aphasia will help? Or maybe Agnosia?

Answer (score 1):

What you may be looking for is

> **agnosia** - the inability to process sensory information.

This is mainly associated with the inability to process sounds, as in notes etc. so it doesn't necessarily refer to the lyrics of songs.

On the other hand, there also is a condition called

> **high frequency hearing loss**.

This article is about it:

http://www.healthyhearing.com/report/52448-Understanding-high-frequency-hearing-loss

and I think that's what you're looking for as it covers the inability to correctly process words.
High frequency hearing loss can affect some consonants: s,h,f or female voices.